# DataDog Directory file matching pattern fails to match any files

Tags: regex, datadog, fnmatch

The directory contains more than 20 files.
As explained in the [DataDog directory documentation](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/directory/datadog_checks/directory/data/conf.yaml.example), a maximum of 20 files can be tracked.

So I tried to configure the data dog directory configuration

```
init_config:

instances:
  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/SalesorderPosition
    pattern: '20([0-9][0-9]_12_+.*).csv'
    filegauges: true
```

Files are in the next format `yyyy_mm_SalesorderPosition.csv`
and I need to show the latest month in all previus years.

When the pattern is enabled in the config, no files are matched. When I remove it files are counted.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the doc you linked. The pattern is a `fnmatch` pattern, not Regex.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html

UPDATE:

The exact working solution would be

```
init_config:

instances:
  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/SalesorderPosition
    pattern: '*_12_SalesorderPosition.csv'
    filegauges: true
```